# `rescue in parse_string' error when running rails app on aws amazon linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

[EDIT] I'm running ruby 1.9.3 on my local machine and ruby 2.0.0 on aws. Rails version 4.1.6.

I have a rails app that I made on my local windows 8 machine. I am getting the following error when running `rails server`:

```
[myusername@ip-172-31-46-144 PROJECT_NAME]$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string': Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '[{"content-type":"ap': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string) (JSON::ParserError)
        from /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
        from /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
        from /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
        from /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
        from /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:334:in `load'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:201:in `load_from_json'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:59:in `block in load_json'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:58:in `each'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:58:in `load_json'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:87:in `load'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types.rb:288:in `load_default_mime_types'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types.rb:315:in `<class:Types>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.1/lib/mime/types.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail.rb:9:in `<module:Mail>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:50:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
        from /home/myusername/PROJECT_NAME/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/myusername/PROJECT_NAME/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /home/myusername/PROJECT_NAME/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/myusername/PROJECT_NAME/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/myusername/PROJECT_NAME/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I found others had this issue with a different context. In particular, the solution was to delete ~/.vagrant.d but I do not have this

https://github.com/semmypurewal/node-dev-bootstrap/issues/13

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the gem by typing `gem install json`